# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8082/api/countries

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, cors

Problem

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/api/countries' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
checkout.component.ts:153     GET http://localhost:8082/api/countries net::ERR_FAILED
```

[angualr](/questions/tagged/angualr)I am configure in server side using spring-boot :

```
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(allowOrigin));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
```

where **allowOrigin**: http://localhost:4200

where using rest api: pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

where my country code:

```
package com.kaushik.bookstore.repository;

import com.kaushik.bookstore.entity.Country;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@RepositoryRestResource
@CrossOrigin
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Bearer Authentication")
@Tag(
        name = "Country",
        description = "Here, GET all details of countries endpoint."
)
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer> {
}
```

Adding Rest App config:

```
package com.kaushik.bookstore.config;

import com.kaushik.bookstore.entity.Country;
import com.kaushik.bookstore.entity.Product;
import com.kaushik.bookstore.entity.ProductCategory;
import com.kaushik.bookstore.entity.State;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.EntityType;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RestAppConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Value("${allowed-origins}")
    private String[] allowOrigin;

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        HttpMethod[] theUnsupportedActions = {HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.PUT,HttpMethod.PATCH, HttpMethod.DELETE};
        disableHttpsMethods(Product.class, config, theUnsupportedActions);
        disableHttpsMethods(ProductCategory.class, config, theUnsupportedActions);
        disableHttpsMethods(Country.class, config, theUnsupportedActions);
        disableHttpsMethods(State.class, config, theUnsupportedActions);
        exposeIds(config);
        cors.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins(allowOrigin);
    }
}
```

In Angular 15 I am using:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.formService.getCountries().subscribe((data) => {
      this.countries = data;
    });
}
```

In Form service:**http://localhost:8082/api/countries
**

```
export class FormService {
  private countriesUrl = 'http://localhost:8082/api' + '/countries';
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<GetResponseCountries>(this.countriesUrl)
      .pipe(map((response) => response.countries));
  }
}
```

In Interceptor:

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { exhaustMap, Observable, take } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.authService.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      exhaustMap((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
        let tokenStr = `Bearer ${user?.token}`;
        const modifyReq = req.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Authorization', tokenStr)
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
        });
        return next.handle(modifyReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Problem: Still getting CORS Error what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Proposing some steps to debug:

1. Remove `@CrossOrigin` from `CountryRepository` since you already defined a global CORS policy in `RestAppConfig`.
2. Double-check the allowOrigin in RestAppConfig - it should be 'http://localhost:4200' in your case
3. You can also try another way to set up your filter in `RestAppConfig`:

```java
cors.addMapping("/**")
    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
    .allowedHeaders("*")
    .allowedOrigins(allowOrigin)
    .allowCredentials(true);
```

4. Make sure `@Value("${allowed-origins}")` is getting the correct value from your properties file (!)

And try clearing your browser cache lastly, browsers can hold onto old CORS policies and create confusion

Comment: Not Working!! I have apply you way to add on **RestAppConfig**